# Postgres: SELECTing bytea data partially with offset and length

Tags: postgresql, bytea

I have a table containing a bytea column, with an average entry size of 5MB. Is it possible to query from random points in the bytea data (given an offset and length of data required) instead of SELECTing the whole byte string into the memory?

Answer (score 3):

Of course, just use the `substring` function:

```
select substring(bytea_contents from offset for length) FROM table;
```

or `get_byte(bytea_contents,offset)` to get a single byte as an integer.

See [Binary String Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-binarystring.html) in the doc for all functions.

Comment: Is this efficient? Or does it actually read the whole column and discards unwanted output ?

Comment: It depends. If the contents got compressed, it will have to read the whole column. See [heap_tuple_untoast_attr_slice](https://doxygen.postgresql.org/tuptoaster_8c_source.html#l00258) in the source code for the implementation.